# Simple marker anchor point settings get back to default after saving the shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-2, anchor-point

On QGIS 2.8 I am trying to use data definition to define a cliff hashmark.

I have created a style for the line with a simple marker and plan to use the vertical anchor point offset to move the marker to the proper side of the line.

I have created a string field and enter *"bottom"* or *"top"* into the field. After creating the line the hashmarks are displayed correctly. However, as soon as I save the shapefile it defaults back to a centered anchor point.

Am I missing a step somewhere or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to update to 2.8.2 or later - that problem was solved back in 2.8.2.